# How can i activate a progress bar using a button in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, button, progress-bar, materialize

I want to add a progress bar using materialize in my project and I want to start the progress bar in a button click instead that it will just keep running from the beginning to the end. This is my html progress bar code:

```
<div class="preloader-wrapper big active">
    <div class="spinner-layer spinner-blue-only">
        <div class="circle-clipper left">
            <div class="circle"></div>
        </div><div class="gap-patch">
        <div class="circle"></div>
    </div><div class="circle-clipper right">
        <div class="circle"></div>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I deactivate it and re-activate it after a button click for example?

Comment: where is the code that you have already tried?  Please see this tutorial:  [ask]  which explains what elements go into a good question.

Comment: this is my code. this just makes a progressbar on the screen and just activates it. i dont know what to change so it will be disactivated, and then a button click to reactivate it

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

As per https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Comment: i want when i run the code that the progressbar will be disactivated and only if i press a button it will activate. i know how to create a button but i dont know how to make the progressbar activated\disactivated

Comment: Can't you use an event listener triggering a function?  The function can call whatever you have activating the progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

An an `id` to your progress bar (let's say `id="loader"`) so your code will look like this:

```
<div id="loader" class="preloader-wrapper big active">
   [...]
```

And toggle its `display` attribute with this script:

```
function toggleLoader() {
    var x = document.getElementById("loader");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Link this script to a button to trigger it, with:

```
<button onclick="toggleLoader()">Click Me</button>
```

---

Working example:

```js
function toggleLoader() {
    var x = document.getElementById("loader");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggleLoader()">Click Me</button>


<svg id="loader" width="64px" height="64px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid" class="lds-rolling" style="display:none;"><circle cx="50" cy="50" fill="none" ng-attr-stroke="{{config.color}}" ng-attr-stroke-width="{{config.width}}" ng-attr-r="{{config.radius}}" ng-attr-stroke-dasharray="{{config.dasharray}}" stroke="#3be8b0" stroke-width="10" r="35" stroke-dasharray="164.93361431346415 56.97787143782138" transform="rotate(149.836 50 50)"><animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" calcMode="linear" values="0 50 50;360 50 50" keyTimes="0;1" dur="1s" begin="0s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animateTransform></circle></svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign an ID to the animation tag within your `<svg>`  `<circle>` element then simple deactivate it like you would with any other HTML element

```
<animateTransform id="progressBarAnimation" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" calcMode="linear" values="0 50 50;360 50 50" keyTimes="0;1" dur="1s" begin="0s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animateTransform></circle></svg>
```

then  do

```
document.getElementById("progressBarAnimation").type = "none";
```